# How do you roll dodge with the dual Guns?

Tags: splatoon-2

I have seen people roll on the floor left or right to dodge attacks with the dual guns. How do you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While shooting with any dualies, hold a direction and press B to dodge that way. You can dodge up to two times in a row.